# Remove duplicate text from multiple strings

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
a = "This is Product A with property B and propery C. Buy it now!"
b = "This is Product B with property X and propery Y. Buy it now!"
c = "This is Product C having no properties. Buy it now!"
```

I'm looking for an algorithm that can do:

```
> magic(a, b, c)
=> ['A with property B and propery C', 
    'B with property X and propery Y', 
    'C having no properties']
```

I have to find for duplicates in 1000+ texts. Super performance isn't a must, but would be nice.

-- Update

I'm looking for sequence of words. So if:

```
d = 'This is Product D with text engraving: "Buy". Buy it now!'
```

The first "Buy" should not be a duplicate. I'm guessing I have to use a threshold of *n* words following eachother in order to be seen as duplicate.

Comment: question is not clear? how to define duplicate text?

Comment: Why `with property` is not duplicated while it is duplicated? :D

Comment: 1) If there was a fourth string "Bumblebee zebra." would `magic( a, b, c, d)` be expected to return all four strings un-modified? 2) How is positional information expected to be used e.g. the example `magic` removes "Buy it now!" despite the fact this is a different part of the strings. Possibly you are looking for a `diff` function?

Comment: @Babai: I was hoping the example pseudo code would help to understand my problem. The duplicates in a, b and c are 'This is Product' and '. Buy it now'.

Comment: @fl00r because var c doesn't have 'with property'

Comment: @NeilSlater: 1) Yes 2) Good one~ I'm going to have a look at diff

Answer (score 3):

```
def common_prefix_length(*args)
  first = args.shift
  (0..first.size).find_index { |i| args.any? { |a| a[i] != first[i] } }
end

def magic(*args)
  i = common_prefix_length(*args)
  args = args.map { |a| a[i..-1].reverse }
  i = common_prefix_length(*args)
  args.map { |a| a[i..-1].reverse }
end
```

---

```
a = "This is Product A with property B and propery C. Buy it now!"
b = "This is Product B with property X and propery Y. Buy it now!"
c = "This is Product C having no properties. Buy it now!"

magic(a,b,c)
# => ["A with property B and propery C",
#     "B with property X and propery Y",
#     "C having no properties"]
```

Comment: I like that your solution looks at sequences instead of individual words!

Answer (score 3):

Your data

```
sentences = [ 
  "This is Product A with property B and propery C. Buy it now!",
  "This is Product B with property X and propery Y. Buy it now!",
  "This is Product C having no properties. Buy it now!"
]
```

Your magic

```
def magic(data)
  prefix, postfix = 0, -1
  data.map{ |d| d[prefix] }.uniq.compact.size == 1 && prefix += 1 or break  while true
  data.map{ |d| d[postfix] }.uniq.compact.size == 1 && prefix > -postfix && postfix -= 1 or break  while true
  data.map{ |d| d[prefix..postfix] }
end
```

Your output

```
magic(sentences)
#=> [
#=>   "A with property B and propery C",
#=>   "B with property X and propery Y",
#=>   "C having no properties"
#=> ]
```

Or you can use `loop` instead of `while true`

```
def magic(data)
  prefix, postfix = 0, -1
  loop{ data.map{ |d| d[prefix] }.uniq.compact.size == 1 && prefix += 1 or break }
  loop{ data.map{ |d| d[postfix] }.uniq.compact.size == 1 && prefix > -postfix && postfix -= 1 or break }
  data.map{ |d| d[prefix..postfix] }
end
```

Comment: When `data` happens to be an array of identical strings, your `magic` will not terminate. You have to check for the `prefix` and `postfix` indices that the character in `d` at that position exists.

Answer (score 0):

**edit: this code has bugs. Just leaving my answer for reference and because i dont like it if people delete answers after being downvoted. Everyone makes mistakes :-)**

I liked @falsetru's approach but felt the code was unnecessarily complex. Here's my attempt:

```
def common_prefix_length(strings)
  i = 0
  i += 1 while strings.map{|s| s[i] }.uniq.size == 1
  i
end

def common_suffix_length(strings)
  common_prefix_length(strings.map(&:reverse))
end

def uncommon_infixes(strings)
  pl = common_prefix_length(strings)
  sl = common_suffix_length(strings)
  strings.map{|s| s[pl...-sl] }
end
```

As the OP may be concerned about performance, i did a quick benchmark:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'securerandom'

prefix = 'PREFIX '
suffix = ' SUFFIX'
test_data = Array.new(1000) do
  prefix + SecureRandom.hex + suffix
end

def fl00r_meth(data)
  prefix, postfix = 0, -1
  data.map{ |d| d[prefix] }.uniq.size == 1 && prefix += 1 or break  while true
  data.map{ |d| d[postfix] }.uniq.size == 1 && postfix -= 1 or break  while true
  data.map{ |d| d[prefix..postfix] }
end

def falsetru_common_prefix_length(*args)
  first = args.shift
  (0..first.size).find_index { |i| args.any? { |a| a[i] != first[i] } }
end

def falsetru_meth(*args)
  i = falsetru_common_prefix_length(*args)
  args = args.map { |a| a[i..-1].reverse }
  i = falsetru_common_prefix_length(*args)
  args.map { |a| a[i..-1].reverse }
end

def padde_common_prefix_length(strings)
  i = 0
  i += 1 while strings.map{|s| s[i] }.uniq.size == 1
  i
end

def padde_common_suffix_length(strings)
  padde_common_prefix_length(strings.map(&:reverse))
end

def padde_meth(strings)
  pl = padde_common_prefix_length(strings)
  sl = padde_common_suffix_length(strings)
  strings.map{|s| s[pl...-sl] }
end

compare do
  fl00r do
    fl00r_meth(test_data.dup)
  end

  falsetru do
    falsetru_meth(*test_data.dup)
  end

  padde do
    padde_meth(test_data.dup)
  end
end
```

These are the results:

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
fl00r is similar to padde
padde is faster than falsetru by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
```

Comment: May the downvoter have the kindness of explaining his objections?

Comment: When data happens to be an array of identical strings, your code will not terminate. You have to check for the `i` index that the character in the string at that position exists.

Comment: Your code is similar to my first edition answer. I changed to current edition because I thought creating/destorying intermediate array (`map{..}.uniq.size`) could cause performance loss. According to your benchmark, I was wrong. ;)